# How to run any 1 module without having to run main.dart?

Tags: flutter, modularization, flutter-module

How to run any one module in Flutter without having to run main.dart?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run any module then it must have the main function defined, as it is the entry point to any dart or flutter app. Just right-click any dart file you want to run and select Run in Android Studio. The run option won't show if the dart file doesn't define the run method. In VS Code you can create a run configuration pointing to a specific file.

Comment: Could you help me how I can have the main function defined?

Comment: the main function is generated when you generate a new flutter project!, it is called main.dart